# Connecting to Google Cloud SQL using proxy -- Error 403: Insufficient Permission

Tags: go, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine

```
EDIT:
```

I now think the issue is with my Golang pod communicating with the proxy pod via localhost, as in the second error message.

I added the service account credentials JSON file to my Docker image's `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. After doing that, using `my-project:us-central1:my-instance` as `connName` below works.

However, when I try using the `DB_HOST` environment variable in the container as `connName`, I still get the 404 error below.

```
ORIGINAL POST
```

I'm following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine) to connect to Google Cloud SQL from a pod on Kubernetes Engine. The pod is running two containers: one with the Cloud SQL proxy image and another with a Golang service to do the actual database queries.

I'm getting the following error when my Golang service tries to initiate a connection:

> ensure that the Cloud SQL API is enabled for your project
>   (https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin).
>   Error during createEphemeral for
>   my-project:us-central1:my-instance: googleapi: Error 403:
>   Insufficient Permission, insufficientPermission

I've looked at a few threads here and elsewhere and here's what I've done so far:

- Ensured the Cloud SQL API is in fact enabled.
- Added the `Editor` role to the service account I'm using.
- Removed and re-added the `Cloud SQL Client` role on the service account I'm using.
- Verified the correct secrets were created, with the same namespace as the pods.

Below is a snippet of the Golang code I'm using, which was taken from [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#languages):

```
cfg := mysql.Cfg(connName, dbUser, dbPassword)
cfg.DBName = dbName
db, err := mysql.DialCfg(cfg)

if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return c.NoContent(http.StatusInternalServerError)
}
```

`connName` is the same string that shows up in the error: `my-project:us-central1:my-instance`. I've tried changing that to `127.0.0.1:3306` instead, but I then get this error below:

> ensure that the account has access to "127.0.0.1:3306" (and make sure
>   there's no typo in that name). Error during createEphemeral for
>   127.0.0.1:3306: googleapi: got HTTP response code 404 with body: Not Found

Also, here is a snippet of the yaml file I'm using to deploy the pods.

```
    env: 
    - name: DB_HOST
      value: 127.0.0.1:3306
    - name: DB_USER
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: cloudsql-db-credentials
          key: username
    - name: DB_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: cloudsql-db-credentials
          key: password
  - name: cloudsql-proxy
    image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
    command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
              "-instances=my-project:us-central1:my-instance=tcp:3306",
              "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
    volumeMounts:
      - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
        mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
        readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
      secret:
        secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
```

I've also verified that the Cloud SQL proxy starts without issue:

```
2018/04/21 20:41:19 Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for my-project:us-central1:my-instance
2018/04/21 20:41:19 Ready for new connections
```

I'm not sure what else to try here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: @rexposadas I didn't, but I suspect specifying the port on the cloudsql-proxy container might fix it:        `ports:
          - containerPort: 3306
            protocol: TCP`

Answer (score 0):

Hi as you can read here [1]: "If your program is written in Go you can use the Cloud SQL Proxy as a library, avoiding the need to start the Proxy as a companion process.", So you are already using the SQL proxy as code and there is no need to use the SQL proxy as a POD.

If you still want to use the SQL proxy as a POD, you can use the GO Companion Process as you can read here[2] under: "Companion Process":

```
import (
        "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s)/%s",
       dbUser,
       dbPassword,
       "127.0.0.1:3306",
       dbName)
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dsn)
```

[1] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy#to-use-inside-a-go-program
[2] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#languages